# Accessing Azure Website on single machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a web application hosted on Azure created in ASP.net, that has a user login page and a separate admin login page. The database being used is MySQL. Recently a new requirement was added by client that admin login page should only be accessible on a single machine that will be allocated by client, different from the user login page which can be accessed by any machine.

One solution could have been to get the mac address of the client machine and comparing it with some database entry but after a lot of searching, I found that there is no way to get the mac address of the client machine except, if the client and server are on the same subnet. But that is not my case, since web app is hosted on azure, and client machine can be anywhere in the world.

IP Address cannot be used to restrict access to the admin portal, since the admin client machine is on a dynamic ip address, and that can change. Also cannot use ssl certificates, because those will restrict the usage of the other user machines for user login as well.

The workflow will be like this, admin opens the page on the browser on their machine, and after providing login information, it will be checked if the machine that is accessing that page is the one authorized to access admin portal or not. So, is there any way I can achieve this, to allow the admin login on only one machine?

Comment: There are multiple ways of identifying a client machine. You could for example use a client certificate or alternatively its IP address. Please read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated further information regarding this. Also, IP Address cannot be used to restrict access to the admin portal, since the admin client machine is on a dynamic ip address, and that can change. Also cannot use ssl certificates, because those will restrict the usage of the other user machines for user login as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be a DB entry for your Admin. So that when the Admin logs into the Admin Portal, you'll update the Entry for the Admin as "logged in". Then you can check on every login if the Admin is already logged in.

Comment: Even if I implement this, admin will be able to login through any machine by simply using that web address and login information, even if it is for the first time. My problem is to restrict the admin login to be performed on only a single machine.

Comment: It depends on how you setup your architecture, you have to tell the login form that it wasn't successfull to log the admin in, because there is already someone logged in as an admin.

Comment: Yes, this restricts that admin can be logged in once, and while that session is in progress, admin won't be allowed to login again, but my problem was to restrict the admin to login from only one machine, even if it is multiple times or multiple browsers.

Comment: So, you can map the IP with the State that he is logged in in the DB. I think I don't get your problem right. Just set the Flags for that Account in the DB and check it at the login. If AdminAlreadyLogged in && AdminHasSameIp -> show Admin panel. The same goes for AdminAlreadyLoggedIn == false && AdminHasSameIp -> show admin panel. Every Time the login as an Admin was successful, you need to store the IP from that Machine.